# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Even though I have the key property added

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I understand the issue here being that each child in a list requires a unique key but I am doing that and it still is not working. Could anyone give me any tips why please? If you could please look at the line with the asterisks, that is the line where I have added my key and yet I still get this warning. Thank you in advance.

```
    "use client";
import {auth} from "../../../utils/firebase";
import {useAuthState} from "react-firebase-hooks/auth"; 
import {useRouter} from "next/navigation"; 
import Message from "../components/message";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { collection, deleteDoc, doc, onSnapshot, query, where} from "firebase/firestore";
import {db} from "../../../utils/firebase";
import {BsTrash2Fill} from 'react-icons/bs';
import {AiFillEdit} from 'react-icons/ai';  
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Dashboard(){
    const route = useRouter();
    const [user,loading] = useAuthState(auth);
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]); 
    
    //See if user is logged in 
    console.log(user);
    const getData = async () => {
        if(loading) return;
        if (!user) return route.push('/auth/login');  
        const collectionRef = collection(db, "posts");
        const q = query(collectionRef, where("user", "==", user.uid));
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
            setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc)=> ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
        });
        return unsubscribe;  
    }
    //Delete Post
    const deletePost = async(id) => {
        const docRef =  doc(db, "posts", id)  
        await deleteDoc(docRef);
    }
    //Get users data
    useEffect(()=>{
        getData();
    },[user,loading]); 
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Your Posts</h1>
                **<div>
                    {posts.map((post)=>{
                        return (<Message{...post} key ={post.id}> <div className="flex gap-4">**
                        <button onClick = {()=> deletePost(post.id)}className="text-pink-600 flex items-center justify-center gap-2 py-2 text-sm  "><BsTrash2Fill className="text-2xl "/>Delete</button> 
                        <Link href = {{pathname: "/post", query: post}}><button className="text-teal -600 flex items-center justify-center gap-2 py-2 text-sm  "><AiFillEdit  className="text-2xl "/>Edit</button> </Link>   
                        </div> </Message> 
                    );
                    })}
                </div>
                <button className= "font-medium text-white bg-gray-800 py-2 px-4 my-6 "onClick={()=> auth.signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by adding the key prop before the spread operator. Such as:

```
posts.map((post)=>{
                        return (<Message key ={post.id} {...post} >
```

instead of

```
{posts.map((post)=>{
                        return (<Message{...post} key ={post.id}>
```

There is more information on this solution over here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/55642

Answer (score 0):

There may be one or more duplicate id's in your `posts` array which causes this error message.

Optionally, you can use array items' indexes as `key`s while using `map` function:

```
{
  posts.map((post, index)=> {
    return (<Message key={index}/>)  
  })
}
```

Even if this solution works for you, don't forget to check your posts array for duplicate id's.

Comment: That does not seem to work. I have also checked if there are duplicate id's in my posts array in my firebase database and there does not seem to be. Am I checking in the right place?

Comment: I was able to fix it by adding the key prop before the spread operator. Here is more information on this solution.[link] https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/55642